# how to convert the entity map to json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I found the map in javascript could not convert to json string like this:

```
let m= new Map<string,string>();
m.set("a","b");
console.log("json:" + JSON.stringify(m));
```

the result look like: `m:{}` .what should I do to convert the map to json, I also found the javascript model that contains map will return {}. If the entity like this:

```
export interface TexFileModel { 
    id: number; 
    m: Map<string,string>
}
```

how to make sure the TexFileModel convert to json with the map datatype?

Comment: a Map can't be represented in JSON - depending on the key type, you could `JSON.stringify([...m])` to at least get something

Comment: ... or even `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(m))`